# getline(cin, STRING) is reading a space

Tags: c++, readline, cin

I have a function which should very simply read in a line of text, but for whatever reason, it only reads a space. I tried changing the readline to a cin >> line, and that worked. But the readline(cin, string) does not.

```
void AddRestaurant() {
    string restToAdd;
    cout << "What is the name of the restaurant you want to add?" << endl;
    getline(cin, restToAdd);
    restuarants.push_back(restToAdd);
    cout << restToAdd + " has been added" << endl << endl;
}
```

Anybody see my error?

Comment: You don't check if getline (not readline) actually read anything - you should check the return value of every function that performs a read, as they can all fail  for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Yes, your error is very obvious: your question fails to meet all the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. That's your problem.

Comment: Are you pushing back to a vector? if not that could be an error

Comment: Most likely, there is previous input left over in `cin` from earlier code, which `getline()` is then reading but `operator>>` is skipping. `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace including line breaks (unless `std::noskipws` is used), whereas `getline()` reads everything up to a specified delimiter (line break by default) without skipping.

Comment: See [Why does std::getline skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is **not an error**. It seems that you have done a `cin>>` operation earlier. `cin>>` takes just the **string from the stream** and leaves behind the `\n`, which the `getline()`, probably picks up, and as you know its **default delimiter** is `\n`, so it just skips the input.

**Solution**---> using `cin.ignore()` before every `getline ()` operation to clear the input stream of any stray `\n`.

**Your call can be:**

```
std::cin.ignore ();
std::getline (cin, restToAdd);
```

**Instead of:**

```
std::getline (cin,restToAdd);
```

Comment: It is often better to put the `ignore` after the `>>` that left the end of line in the stream. 2 reasons: The fix is closer to the source of the problem so the two may be more easily visually tied together when reading through the code and if someone calls `AddRestaurant` and there isn't an end of line in the stream, the first byte of the restaurant's name just got discarded.